# SQL - Image Storage - Store Base64 string or FilePath

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm busy working with a web application which will have a catalog of products.

Each product can have several images attached.
Each catalog can have 1000s of products.

At scale, is it better to store the file paths to the image or the actual Base64 representation of the image within the SQL Server Database (Azure hosted)?

I'm particularly concerned about the cost implications due to the larger DB size when storing Base64 strings as opposed to simple file paths.

Thanks!

Comment: Files go in the `file` system.

Comment: [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) might be what you are looking for

Comment: @michaelmesser I will have a look - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving files in databases is not a good idea. As we know, the performance that querying blobs or large text in SQL is awful and it also greatly cost DB server memory. Saving URLs in DB only is recommended.

If you are using Azure Cloud, you can save your files in [Azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-overview). And you can save your file storage blob URL in your DB table.

Azure blob storage is optimized for storing massive amounts of unstructured data. Unstructured data is data that doesn't adhere to a particular data model or definition, such as text or binary data.

For saving files, it is much cheaper than Azure SQL storage, you can see its [pricing list here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/).

Comment: Thank you @stanley - I appreciate the comprehensive answer. This confirms all the research I've done since posting. I will most certainly be proceeding with Azure Blob Storage with links(file paths) stored in the DB tables.